# Vue 3 problem rendering child of the child components

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, webpack-5, webpack-cli

I created a `Vue 3.0.5` application using `Webpack 5.21.2` and `Webpack CLI 4.5.0`. I build a global component **my-component.js**:

```js
import SecondComponent from './second-component.vue';
app.component('global-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Hi!</h1>
      <second-component></second-component>
    </div>
  `,
 components: {
   SecondComponent
 }
})
```

The imported **second-component.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{someData}}</div>
    <third-component :name="helloWorld"></third-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ThirdComponent from './third-component.vue';
export default {
 name: 'second-component',
 components: {
   ThirdComponent 
 },
 data: function () {
   return {
     someData: 'Just some data!',
     helloWorld: 'Hello World!',
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

The third component **third-component.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{name}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'third-component',
  props: {
    name: String,
  }
}
</script>
```

Here are the webpack configuration **webpack.config.js**:

```js
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    global_component: './global-component.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}`,
    filename: '[name]_bundled.js'
  },
  resolve: {
   extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
}
```

The bundle file i'm using in **index.html** like this:

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.5/vue.global.js"></script>
  <script>const app = Vue.createApp({});</script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="global_component_bundled.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <global-component></global-component>
  </div>
  <script>app.mount("#app");</script>
</body>
```

The problem I get is that the child of the child component is not rendering. In my case, this is the component **third-component.vue** that i'm importing into **second-component.vue**. However, when i use the component **third-component.vue** directly into **my-component.js**, it works. Can someone explain why and how can i solve that? Here i have an [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/webpack5-vue3-tx8vp).

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i have a bundle file at the end and the problem is that ```third-component.vue``` is not rendering.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim here you can have a look https://codesandbox.io/s/webpack5-vue3-tx8vp?file=/package.json

Comment: it looks like `<third-component name="helloWorld"></third-component>` is not parsed when I inspect the page I see it there

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yeah, is not rendering as i wrote in my post (or there are difference between parsing and rendering? if yes then i should to change the name of the post) but the question is why? i was also inspecting in browser with brake points and the break point is not firing on that component.

Comment: I think the nested component is ignored during the bundling process, your way looks like a bad practice, I think using `main.js` with root instance would solve the issue

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yeah the problem is that i can't to this because i have in my project pages where some components are referenced with an script-Tag. With Vue 2 that worked perffectly but with Vue 3 not (if you have another idea i'm open for it). But you don't know why this problem is ocure?

Comment: As I said this should be a parsing issue because you're using a CDN script and bundled file

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim but why this problem come? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I searched for a solution for a long time and in the end I got it. I used `vue` from `CDN` and in this case I should to say `webpack` to use the external `Vue`. Just make this configuration changes in **webpack.config.js**:

```js
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = {
 ...
 externals: {
   // Here you tell webpack to take Vue from CDN
   vue: "Vue"
 },
 ...
}
```

With these changes `webpack` bundle the component and take `Vue` from `CDN`. I hope this answer will help other people. Here i made the changes already: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/webpack5-vue3-with-externals-brxlf?file=/webpack.config.js).

Comment: Thank you, you just ended a 3 hour headache